# Can any one explain to me "to pay his way through"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

> A poor man was selling goods door to door to pay his way through medical school

What does "to pay his way through" mean here? Is it an idiom?

Comment: "To pay your way" means to earn enough money to pay for something by instalments (e.g. daily, weekly, monthly, etc.) In your example, the man was working to pay for his medical education, probably on a term-by-term basis. You can also "work your way" by offering your labour in lieu of payment.

Comment: why he used the word through medical school ??

Comment: Good point. Because he had to make regular payments, from start to finish. I'm not sure if *through* is the only preposition that can be used with this idiom. It possibly is.

Comment: @Mick can you clarify me why through is used there

Comment: It is the only preposition that will fit. *Through* means ["from one end or side of something to the other"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/through).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to pay his way through**

- **To pay**: to fund/support
- **His way**: his undertaking/endeavour
- **Through**: for the duration of

I suppose you could call it an idiom.

Comment: thanks for your clear and detailed explanation.Once again Thanks a lot